# In R tidymodels how do I set the default level for evaluating a logistic model

Tags: r, tidymodels

I would like to tell `yardstick` that the default level for my logistic model is the second level.  I know I can specify individual statistics with `event_level = "second"` but I would prefer to set the event_level with a global option.  When I try it does not seem to work.

```r
library(tidymodels)
data("two_class_example")
sens(two_class_example, truth, predicted, event_level = "second")
#> # A tibble: 1 × 3
#>   .metric .estimator .estimate
#>   <chr>   <chr>          <dbl>
#> 1 sens    binary         0.793

options(yardstick.event_level = "second")
sens(two_class_example, truth, predicted)
#> # A tibble: 1 × 3
#>   .metric .estimator .estimate
#>   <chr>   <chr>          <dbl>
#> 1 sens    binary         0.880
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

On 2020-07-13 we moved away from the global option. In the current version (1.2.0), setting this option will now produce an warning, but won’t have any effect.

Comment: Thanks for the information Max.  I see no warning in the reprex above.  I see in the code a depreciation warning if I use yardstick.event_first but not yardstick.event_level.  Is there any way to specify the event level for all the modeling in a project?

Comment: I had seen the reference to `yardstick.event_level = `option here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68561374/logistic-regression-with-tidymodels-how-to-set-event-level-second-in-last-fi.  Is that bogus?

Comment: This seems like black magic but I think it works. my_yardstick_event_level <- function() {
  "second"
}

assignInNamespace(
  "yardstick_event_level", 
  my_yardstick_event_level, 
  ns = "yardstick"
) Max is there a better way to do this?